# how to create hexagon Spiral rings in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[I tried to generate the hexagons so they look like a honeycomb, provided that each layer is only a multiple of 6 hexagons. as well as the generate flow as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxmKn.png)

I tried to generate a honeycomb pattern using the provided code. I expected the pattern to have evenly spaced hexagons with equal sides. However, the actual result was a pattern with hexagons that were not evenly spaced and had different side lengths.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateHexFloor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Hexagon;
    public uint Radius;
    public float HexSideMultiplier = 1;

private const float sq3 = 1.7320508075688772935274463415059f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    // Point of the next hexagon to be spawned
    Vector2 currentPoint = transform.position;

    if (Hexagon.transform.localScale.x != Hexagon.transform.localScale.y)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Hexagon has not uniform scale: cannot determine its side. Aborting");
        return;
    }

    // Spawn scheme: nDR, nDX, nDL, nUL, nUX, End??, UX, nUR
    Vector2[] mv = {
        new Vector2(1.5f, -sq3 * 0.5f),    // DR
        new Vector2(0, -sq3),               // DX
        new Vector2(-1.5f, -sq3 * 0.5f),    // DL
        new Vector2(-1.5f, sq3 * 0.5f),     // UL
        new Vector2(0, sq3),                // UX
        new Vector2(1.5f, sq3 * 0.5f)       // UR
    };

    int lmv = mv.Length;
    float HexSide = Hexagon.transform.localScale.x * HexSideMultiplier;

    for (int mult = 0; mult <= Radius; mult++)
    {
        int hn = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < lmv; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mult; i++, hn++)
            {
                GameObject h = Instantiate(Hexagon, currentPoint, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                h.name = string.Format("Hex Layer: {0}, n: {1}", mult, hn);
                currentPoint += mv[j] * HexSide;
            }
            if (j == 4)
            {
                GameObject h = Instantiate(Hexagon, currentPoint, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                h.name = string.Format("Hex Layer: {0}, n: {1}", mult, hn);
                currentPoint += mv[j] * HexSide;
                hn++;
                if (mult == Radius)
                    break;      // Finished
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: for anyone to be able to help you, you should post your code with the used algorithm (as text and not image)

Comment: Please see what I consider the canonical article on the matter: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: @AKX I have looked at the website but there is still a problem with the appearance of 1 additional hexagon on each layer